# logic for checking sequential order in decimal numbers using java

Tags: java

I want to check the sequential order of decimal numbers and find the missing number.
For eg: If i have 1.1.1, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 2.1.1, 2.1.3, 2.1.2, 3, etc
Here i need to find the missing number 1.1.2 and also out of sequence 2.1.2. Kindly help me with logic.

Comment: Done for whole number, confused in the case of decimals.

Comment: 1.1.1 is not a decimal number ;)

Comment: i want logic for both decimal number(1.1,1.2,2.1) and for this numbers..

Comment: it sounds like permutation or combination of 3 elements in lexicographical order...look at here http://the-lost-beauty.blogspot.com/2010/07/generating-combinations-in.html

Comment: These are *version number* strings.

Answer (score 0):

This does sound suspiciously like homework but, here's some hints for the algorithm. For simplicity, not efficiency, try a 2-step approach.

You'll have to treat each value in your initial list as an ordered set of integers. That is the value 2.1.3 is, an ArrayList whose elements are 2, 1, 3.

First determine what's out of sequence - this catches the 2.1.2 value. Something's out of sequence when the value of any part of the n-th element of the list is greater than any part of the (n+1)-th element. Walk through the list of values comparing two at a time; breaking each element into an list of integers.

Second, sort the list and determine if there are gaps. Sorting would still need to treat each value as a set of integers. A gap in the sorted list would be defined as a change
of more than 1 in any part of the two values. Stop comparing 2 values when you find a gap and move onto the next 2 values to compare.

Comment: Thanks for your logic, If i am understanding you correctly is it like first handling set of decimals which starts with 1.1.1,find the missed number or out of order and then proceed on to 2.1.1.This is really taking much time, i tried it. I am trying to handle the sorting and out of order for whole set. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To catch the out of sequence items you're comparing two strings 1.1.2 to 1.1.3 as a two array/arraylists of decimal values. For the corresponding element in each array/arraylist you have a gap if the difference in those elements is not 1.